# Possible to show messageItem in shiny navbarPage?

Tags: r, shiny

Similar to the dropdownMenu and messageItem functions which are available in shinydashboard I would like to show message items on the right hand side of the navbar in a navbarPage based app. Example of the related functions here:  https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html

I have tried inserting the same funcitons into a navbarPage app but it is not working as expected- not right aligned.

As a very basic reproducible example, this is the structure of my app with my attempt at including the message item:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(
    navbarPage("Navbar!",
               tabPanel("Plot",
                   sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(),
                     mainPanel()
                   )
               ),
               tabPanel(
                   dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                                messageItem(
                                    from = "Sales Dept",
                                    message = "Sales are steady this month."
                               )
                   )
               )
    )
)

server = function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not the best at css, but this is a start to getting the result you're looking for. Change the UI to:

```
ui <- shinyUI(
          fluidPage(
              tags$head(
                  tags$style(HTML("
                      .navbar-nav .messages-menu a {padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom:0px}
                      .navbar-nav {width: 90%}
                      .navbar-nav .messages-menu {float: right; padding-top: 25px;}
                  "))
              ),
          navbarPage("Navbar!",
              tabPanel("Plot",
                  sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(),
                      mainPanel()
                  )
              ),
              tabPanel(
                  dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                      messageItem(
                          from = "Sales Dept",
                          message = "Sales are steady this month."
                      )
                  )
              )
         )   
     )
 )
```

The width sets the class navbar-nav to 90% of the width of the screen since it is the space that contains both tab panels but not the label "Navbar!", and the second line takes the class messages-menu within navbar-nav and shifts it to the right of the space filled by navbar-nav (hence why we had to extend the width to include all of the header not occupied by the label; this percentage would likely have to change depending on the text input that is in place of "Navbar!").

Comment: The only issue is that it is rendering on a new row below the level of the Plot tabPanel (making the navbar thicker). I need these on the same level if possible @Amanda

Comment: I agree, I edited my answer to contain updated css. That should work, although again the percentages and px might need to be adjusted depending on what is in the navbar.

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed @Amanda, I have marked as the answer, thanks again